# Push notifications from a library project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've been trying for some time to do push notifications from an Android Library project.

It seems that the message is sent (from the same application instead of server, for simplicity) but GcmListenerService does not call its onMessageReceived method, and therefore I can't display a notification.
I am using this library as an .aar library in an Android application.

Library build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Application build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***.androidlibraryproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'androidlibrary-debug', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}


repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

As you can see I added the dependencies of google services cloud messaging in App's build.gradle as well. This is because it was not working directly from library.

Library AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.***.***">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="8.4.0" /> -->

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.***.***" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="com.***.***.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="com.***.***.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="com.***.***.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Registering the receiver:

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Registration Broadcast Receiver: onReceive");

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);

                if (sentToken)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Token sent successfully.");
                } else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Token did not send.");
                }
            }
        };

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(currentActivity).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
```

Anyway, the main question is - how can I fix it so that the library can receive messages via MyGcmListenerService? Its onMessageReceived method is not being called.

currentActivity is the MainActivity of the application passed to the library for processing.